# Can this jQuery list filtering be done better?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, optimization, logic

I have a web page with a list of items that can each have tags. I want to filter them by tags, using a logical AND to sort them: to be visible an item must have all of the selected tags.

But I also have a special "null" sorting attribute. If it is selected, elements with no tags must remain visible no matter what.

I've implemented it, but, out of curiosity, I tried doing it better, but couldn't. Can this be done with only one condition? Or is this as good as it gets?

```
var activeTags = getAllCurrentlyActiveTags();
$('#list>li').show();
$.each(activeTags, function(index, tag) {
  $('#list>li').each(function() {
    var myTags, keepForNull, notJustNull, currentFailCheck;
    // Array of tags for the current item.
    myTags = getMyTags(this);

    keepForNull = activeTags.indexOf('null') !== -1 && myTags.length === 0;
    notJustNull = tag === 'null' && !(activeTags.length === 1 && activeTags[0] === 'null');
    currentFailCheck = myTags.indexOf(tag) === -1;

    if (keepForNull) {
      return;
    }
    if (notJustNull) {
      return;
    }
    if (currentFailCheck) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you swap the loops (i.e. loop over each item, and within that each tag) then you can do the `keepForNull` logic outside the inner loop, since it doesn't depend on the current tag.

Comment: It looks like you've got a bunch of local variables that should be declared so they aren't implicit globals.

Comment: @sje397 - `keepForNull`, depends upon `myTags.length` which is determined in the inner loop.  I don't think it can move outside that inner loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're right. They were renamed and I forgot to rename them in the declaration. I'll do this now. Thanks.

Comment: @sje397 That first boolean checks if the current item has no tags and therefore should be remain displayed. So it does depend on both the current tag and the current item.

Comment: @jfriend00 Since `myTags` doesn't depend on the current tag it can move outside the loop too. @eje211 No, the `tag` variable does not occur in the `keepForNull` initialisation. Note I said 'swap the loops'.

Answer (score 1):

How about this as a minor improvement?

```
var activeTags = getAllCurrentlyActiveTags();   
//// no need to search the active tags array for 'null' repeatedly 
var hasNull = activeTags.indexOf('null') !== -1;
//// only fetch the list items from the DOM once
$('#list>li').each(function() {
  //// keep a flag so we don't hide and/or show the same item more than once
  var show = true;

  //// only fetch tags for each list item once
  // Array of tags for the current item.
  var myTags = getMyTags(this);

  //// if we're keeping it, skip the loop over tags
  var keepForNull = hasNull && myTags.length === 0;      
  if (!keepForNull) {      
    //// use a for loop so the the early 'break' is clear
    for(var index = 0; index < activeTags.length; index++) {
      var tag = activeTags[index];

      //// simplified but equivalent condition
      var notJustNull = tag === 'null' && activeTags.length !== 1;
      if (notJustNull) {
        continue;
      }

      //// only search myTags array when all other checks pass
      var currentFailCheck = myTags.indexOf(tag) === -1;    
      if (currentFailCheck) {
        show = false;
        //// don't need to look at any more tags
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  //// only show/hide once as appropriate
  show ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
});
```

You could probably improve it further if you can modify the wider logic, in that when the user activates a (non-null) tag, or de-activates the null tag, you only need to look at the visible items to work out which ones to hide. Visa versa for the reverse action.

(OT: I do think it's better to put `var` with the variable - it makes it much easier to scan for accidentally global vars.)